# Display result for mysql query

Tags: mysql

table A

```
id  name group_id email

1   a      1        a@g.com
2   b      3,4      b@g.com
3   c      1,3,4    c@g.com
4   d      2,5,1    d@g.com
```

table b

```
id  user   user_group_id  

1    x       1,3
```

The table structure is as above

OUTPUT: if i search for user_group_id (from table B) for 1,3 in table A then i should get 4 email addresses i.e a@g.com,b@g.com,c@g.com,d@g.com. Since 1 is present in 3 rows in table A and 3 is present in 2 rows.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: First of all you should read about the normalization and normalize your DB structure

Comment: For your case I don't recall if there is a specific function to strip (and iterate) over a string to do the search you want. Best thing I can think off is you to improve your design tables. E.g. a group that has users which is 1-N relationship. Your search would be much more easy.

Comment: Of course, the poster may not have the possibility to change the data-structure...

Comment: glglgl : please refer to the output..

Answer (score 0):

While I don't exactly understand what your problem is, I have the impression that your table structure is not properly normalized.

Your table `b` should have two entries:

```
id  user   user_group_id  

1    x       1
2    x       3
```

In this case, you can properly join your tables and get all answers when querying for a certain user name.